# How to apply load test to Azure Event Hubs triggered consumer function with JMeter to find out consumer's processing speed to egress speed ratio?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, jmeter, load-testing, azure-eventhub

I have an Event Hubs application that I haven't published Azure yet, so it is running in my local with Azure emulator.

My consumer is an Azure Event Hubs triggered function and running in my local. So there are no multiple function instances; only one function instance backed by a single `EventProcessorHost` instance running in my local and there are `2 partitions in the Event Hub`.

The consumer does not do any map/filter operation, but only saves the incoming message to an Azure Blob storage.

I want to do load testing/stress testing with probably JMeter to find out and compare the consumer's processing time with egress(flow of data to consumer from Event Hubs broker). In this way I hope to be able to see whether my consumer is late or not, so the criteria of `consumer's processing speed/egress speed` is the reason of the load test.

I haven't done load testing with JMeter or any other tool before, but I have learned that you can use it to test things from simple APIs to JMS message brokers. API or web page load testing makes sense and looks straightforward, but I'm struggling to fully grasp how to test pub/sub programs. There are some tutorials like [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) I have read, but for .NET side and Event Hub there are no descriptive tutorials that make sense.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it right to run the load test in my local with the consumer function which is running in the Azure emulator and saving to Azure cloud blob storage or should I publish this function to the cloud and run the test in the cloud? Does it affects the results?
2. I couldn't find any JMeter tutorials specific to Event Hubs, so how can I do it with JMeter? Should I have to write any wrapper program?
3. Besides JMeter, if it's not suitable for this task, how can I do load testing with any other way?